# Execute hadoop jar through Spring MVC using process command

Tags: java, hadoop, process, hadoop-yarn

I am new to Java and currently working on a project where a Hadoop job needs to be triggered from Spring MVC application. The manager asked me to use "process" for which I have no clue. I have written a shell script to trigger the job but the client wants it to be triggered directly from the Spring MVC app so that log can be written in local file system.

Can anyone help me how to trigger a Hadoop jar (more specifically Yarn command with different arguments) to be triggered in edge node through Java process?

Comment: personally i'd go ask your manager to direct you to en example of the implementation he/she has in mind. typically when someone says 'do it this way' they either know what they are talking about and have example code in mind, or are trying to act smart which you can catch because they will not be able to show you an example....well that or he/she doesn't care enough about you or success to actually help get it done.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using ProcessBuilder.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html

Comment: I am trying to use processbuilder. But I have an issue where my tomcat doesnt have access to cluster. So I need to login to Edgenode(different server) and execute the command. I know now how to execute the command through process builder but how do i login to different server through processbuilder. (I am aware that we can use Jsch but now looking for solutions in processbuilder only)